# Why can I initialize a class/struct with a scalar value?

Tags: c++, constructor

I came across this behavior today and I can't find a reason for why it's working.

#### Non-working code

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

MyStruct foo = 1;
```

```
error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘MyStruct’ requested
```

#### Working code

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
    MyStruct(int x) : x(x) {
        //
    }
};


MyStruct foo = 1;
```

#### Question

Why does C++ know how to use this constructor? Shouldn't it still be having a compiler error saying that I can't assign an int to a struct? Why don't I need `MyStruct foo = MyStruct(1);`?

[Online GDB link to code](https://onlinegdb.com/Lkk_Isn33)

Comment: `MyStruct foo = 1` is a [copy initialization syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) that calls a constructor. It's just a special syntax for calling constructor, do not let `=` confuse you.

Comment: @RichardCritten At the same time, `foo = 1;` (a statement by itself) may call `MyStruct(int)` constructor implicitly and then assign.

Comment: Look for ["converting constructor"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) or follow the link. `MyStruct(int x)` is implicit converting constructor, make it `explicit MyStruct(int x)` if you want to get an error.

Comment: C++ will generally use any path it can find to convert a given value into the needed type. Sometimes these transformations can get fairly convoluted and unintuitive ([string literals being converted to `bool`](https://godbolt.org/z/M35cT75rP) rather than `std::string`, for example).

Comment: _Recommended viewing:_ In 2019, **Timur Doumler** gave an excellent talk at several popular C++ conferences explaining [Initialisation in modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76887553/22193627).

Comment: The simple answer is "because it has a constructor that takes a scalar value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thanks to everyone for the comments and answers, but the best response came from @273K in a comment.*

The question demonstrates a [**Converting Constructor**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). From the link,

> A converting constructor specifies an implicit conversion from the types of its arguments (if any) to the type of its class.

I created a constructor with a single `int` argument. **This creates an implicit conversion from `int` to `MyStruct`.**

As others mentioned, when writing `MyStruct foo = 1;`, that's actually declaring and initializing an instance of `MyStruct`. During the (copy) initialization, the compiler will be able to find that implicit conversion from `int` to `MyStruct` and call the converting constructor as part of the process.

Comment: It's odd that you say that the best response came in a comment that was made after I had posted an actual answer saying the same thing.

Comment: My apologies Ted, I read everything from top to bottom after it was all posted. And while your answer mentioned the words “conversion constructor,” it wasn’t clear to me as someone who had never heard of this concept that Conversion Constructors are a “Thing” (i.e. they are concept that would have their own wiki page or article about them). My brain honestly didn’t catch the word “conversion” at all. And there was no link about it. Also the lead was buried under some other info. Anyway, if you like I can edit your answer and accept it.

Comment: Aha, then I understand. There's no need to accept my answer since I didn't make it clear enough. Fwiw, all constructors that are not copy/move ctors are conversion constructors snd nowadays those taking only one argument are often made `explicit` to not get accidental conversions. The compiler is allowed to find and apply one implicit conversion which can in some situations lead to confusing results.

Answer (score 3):

There's no conversion constructor from `int` in your original class, but since it is an aggregate, you can use brace initialization:

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

MyStruct foo{1}; // initializes x with 1
```

For the question:

> Why does C++ know how to use this constructor? Shouldn't it still be having a compiler error saying that I can't assign an int to a struct?

The conversion constructor in your second code is *implicit*. Make it `explicit` and you'd get a compilation error.

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
    explicit MyStruct(int x) : x(x) {}
};

//MyStruct foo = 1; // now error
MyStruct foo{1};  // OK
MyStruct foo(1);  // OK
```

Comment: gcc can warn that you will have a partially initialized struct this way  see : https://godbolt.org/z/34b9Ec78h. Which I think is a good thing because this could be a bug

Comment: @PepijnKramer Perhaps not important for the question, but the compiler is just warning you that you may have left it out by mistake. In `MyStruct foo{1};` then `foo` is not partially initialized since `foo.y` _is_ initialized (to `0`).

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't it still be having a compiler error saying that I can't assign an int to a struct?

There is no assignment in your code. The `=` in `MyStruct foo = 1;` is not an assignment operator.

The token `=` is used with multiple meanings in C++. It is used as assignment operator, but here it is part of the syntax for an *initializer* and has nothing to do with assignment. They could have used any other token for that syntax instead.

An initializer of the form `= some_expression` is *copy-initialization* which, if the target type that is to be initialized is a class type, is defined to consider all non-`explicit` conversion functions of `some_expression`'s type (if it is a class type) and all converting constructors of the target class type, i.e. all constructors that can be called with exactly one argument and that are not `explicit`. Overload resolution is then performed to select the conversion function or constructor as if it was called with `some_expression` as only argument.

`MyStruct foo = MyStruct(1);` is (at least since C++17) fully equivalent to `MyStruct foo(1);` which is *direct-initialization* that considers all (whether `explicit` or not) constructors of `MyStruct` to initialize `foo`. As long as you do not intent to use an `explicit` constructor, there is no need to use either of these forms and the first form is only necessary when writing the initializer for a class member, because the syntax immediately using parentheses for the intiializer is not permitted in that context, although since C++11 the parentheses can be replaced with braces with typically similar meaning.